# Redirect Certain Sharepoint Sites to another Sharepoint server

Tags: 2010, 2007, redirect

We are currently migrating some content that exists on a sharepoint 2007 environment to our sharepoint 2010 environment. We have been faced with scenarios where people have links in varios places (bookmarks, documents etc) to the old site, I would like these requests to be re-directed to our new location, however it can only be for certain sites as there is still a good amount of content not yet migrated on the 2007 server. For exmaple:

If a user goes to:

```
http://sp2007.mydomain.com/sites/compliance/documents/mydoc.pdf
```

I would like them to be redirected to:

```
http://sp2010.myotherdomain.com/sites/compliance/documents/mydoc.pdf
```

I am aware you can do something like this with an .htaccess file on apache but not sure how I could accomplish this in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use the URL rewrite module for IIS, which is an extension for IIS Server version >7.

Get it from here: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Here are some articles about how to use it and create rewrite rules:

[Using the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module)

[Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way going forward .

URL rewrite :-

The URL rewrite rule has to be used only in the case where you do not want your default zone to be accessed by end users (normally kept for development work ) .

The web application is then extended for one of the zones say Intranet and URL is redirected from Default to Intranet zone for all the end users.

In your case , since it a migration what you can do is keep the source site read only .
Complete the migration for the required site and then share the target site information around .

This is always the right way going forward.

I know it's a lengthy process but this is the right process .

Don't migrate the links ,let the end users make this configuration change  on their own . User's need to be guided to make the required changes in the bookmarks,links etc.